# Unable to clear unwanted large files from gitlab repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I'm trying to remove some unwanted large files from this branch using the `git filter-repo` command  (`git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 5M --prune-degenerate always --force`) as stated in this GitLab [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/#removing-objects-from-lfs) & also removing the lines of those large files from this `.gitattributes` file however when I try to push the change, I still get this error:-

```
batch response: Your push has been rejected, because this repository has exceeded its size limit of 10 GiB by 2.7 GiB. Please contact your GitLab administrator for more information
```

Following is the terminal output:-

```
$ git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 5M --prune-degenerate always --force
Processed 2862 blob sizes
Parsed 491 commits
New history written in 0.64 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
HEAD is now at aeh9h85 Added model files to model folder
Enumerating objects: 6102, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6102/6102), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2080/2080), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6102/6102), done.
Total 6102 (delta 3871), reused 6071 (delta 3844), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 1.35 seconds.
$ git remote -v
$ git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/xxx/internal/yy/test.git
$ git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/xxx/internal/yy/test.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/xxx/internal/yy/test.git (push)
$ git push --set-upstream origin test-changes -f
batch response: Your push has been rejected, because this repository has exceeded its size limit of 10 GiB by 2.7 GiB. Please contact your GitLab administrator for more information.                                                         
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/xxx/internal/yy/test.git'
```

Comment: Did you check if the files were actually removed from the history after running `filter-repo`?

Comment: may I know how can I verify that? is it through cli command of git or from the UI?

Comment: `git log --name-status` seems like a good starting point. If you prefer GUIs, use a GUI. I often find CLI tools to give better insights and data (especially when working on such a low-level, rewriting complete commit history)

Comment: no, I do not see any changes with respect to large file deletion when I performed that git log --name-status except the modification in the .gitattributes file 

M       .gitattributes

Comment: Then that filter-repo call did not work. Is the head/tip of the branch `aeh9h85` or your old (pre repo-filter) commit?

Comment: It seems like commit hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed these steps and it worked for me:-

Install `git-filter-repo` first and follow the steps below to clear the unwanted LFS:-

```
git filter-repo --force --path /lfs_dir --invert-paths
```

assuming your LFS are inside the directory (/lfs_dir) or modify the above command to point to right directory of LFS that needs to be removed

Then, remove the lines of unwanted LFS from .gitattributes file, and then execute following commands

```
git add .
git commit -m <commit message>
git push --force --all origin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Go to GitLab → Project Repository Settings → General → Advanced and click on ‘Prune unreachable objects’ to prune them now manually.